# Scraping Images from Google Images by using Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm currently learning Scrapy. I try to download some [damaged car images](https://www.google.com/search?q=front%20end%20car%20damage&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwiH3ob2q4ryAhWMCewKHeqqATcQ2-cCegQIABAA) from Google Images. I read the [offical document](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html) and watched [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jMMErSuEJ2g) image scraping video. I try to click the image (in this way the image gets bigger) then scrape the image. However, when I run the code (scrapy crawl downloader) I find nothing. There is no url, no image or no other thing. Even, I get [Crawled (200)] message which I learned this is the success message.

This is my code:

```
import scrapy
from urllib.parse import urljoin

class DownloaderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "downloader"
    start_urls = ["https://www.google.com/search?q=front+end+car+damage&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwiH3ob2q4ryAhWMCewKHeqqATcQ2-cCegQIABAA"]

def parse(self, response):
    products = response.css("div.isv-r.PNCib.MSM1fd.BUooTd").getall()
    print(len(products), " products") #This is a test. I get 0 
    for p in products:
        url = urljoin(response.url, p)
        yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_product)

def parse_product(self, response):
    raw_image_urls = response.css("a.wXeWr.islib.nfEiy div.bRMDjf.islir img.rg_i.Q4LuWd::attr(src)").extract()
    clean_image_urls = []
    for img_url in raw_image_urls:
        clean_image_urls.append(response.urljoin(img_url))
    yield { 
        'image_urls': clean_image_urls
    }
```

This is my settings.py:

```
BOT_NAME = 'downloader'
SPIDER_MODULES = ['downloader.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'downloader.spiders'
ITEM_PIPELINES = {'scrapy.pipelines.images.ImagesPipeline': 1}
IMAGES_STORE = 'local_folder'
USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.131 Safari/537.36"
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False
```

I didn't change anything in the other files. In below you can see the output in the terminal.

```
2021-07-30 11:10:31 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
['scrapy.pipelines.images.ImagesPipeline']
2021-07-30 11:10:31 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2021-07-30 11:10:31 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2021-07-30 11:10:31 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2021-07-30 11:10:32 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.google.com/search?q=front+end+car+damage&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwiH3ob2q4ryAhWMCewKHeqqATcQ2-cCegQIABAA> (referer: None)
0  products
```

As you can see, I've got 0 products after the end of the run. Besides, It creates a local_folder (which is for images) but do not donwload any image. Why is this happening? I'm a newbie as I said. I made research and read other questions in stackoverflow. But I couldn't find anything specific like my issue. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: `200` means that server recognized URL in request and it send response but it doesn't means that it send expected result - it may send captcha or warning for bots/scripts/hackers/etc.

Comment: Google may use JavaScript to add elements but Scrapy doesn't run JavaScript. It would need to use extension like `scrapy-selenium` which runs [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real web browser which can run JavaScript.

Comment: Google has big money to create complex system to detect scripts/bots/hackers - so scraping Google can be more difficult than scraping other pages. But Google should have also API for developers to get access to images without scraping.

Comment: Thank you for your help, Furas. I'll try the extension.

Comment: authors of `scrapy` created also [splash](https://www.zyte.com/splash/) to run JavaScript - and there is modul [scrapy-splash](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash) - but it needs to use `docker`.